# Mock Setup Exception for valid setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have the following classes structure:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public int Number;
}
public interface IService
{
    int ProcessInt(MyObj obj);
}
public class Service : IService
{
    public int ProcessInt(MyObj myObj)
    {
        return myObj.Number;
    }
}
```

and then the consumer class

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Run(IService s)
    {
        var obj = new MyObj {Number = 1};
        Console.WriteLine(s.ProcessInt(obj));
    }
}
```

and then the unit test

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{

    private readonly Mock<IService> _service = new Mock<IService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    private readonly Class1 _sut = new Class1();

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var obj = new MyObj {Number = 1};
        _service.Setup(x => x.ProcessInt(obj)).Returns(1);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestClass1()
    {
        _sut.Run(_service.Object);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I run the unit test, I get "**Moq.MockException : IService.ProcessInt(MoqStuff.MyObj) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.**" which is weird since I have the setup for that input.

Is this an expected behavior of Moq framework? Is there any way I can fix that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this code in your `SetUp` method:

```
var obj = new MyObj {Number = 1};
_service.Setup(x => x.ProcessInt(obj)).Returns(1);
```

Here you set up expectation, that `ProcessInt` is called with this specific object `obj`.

However, in your method `Run` you create another object:

```
var obj = new MyObj {Number = 1};
```

Though property value is the same, this object is totally different from the one you created in your `SetUp` method. This is the reason why you get exception about missing setup.

What you can do instead is set up your service for any input parameter using `It.IsAny`:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _service.Setup(x => x.ProcessInt(It.IsAny<MyObj>())).Returns(1);
}
```

This setup will work for any parameter value.

Or if you want to match only based on some criteria, you can use `It.Is`:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    // setup only for cases where obj.Number == 1
    _service
        .Setup(x => x.ProcessInt(It.Is<MyObj>(o => o.Number == 1 )))
        .Returns(1);

    // setup only for cases where obj.Number == 2
    _service
        .Setup(x => x.ProcessInt(It.Is<MyObj>(o => o.Number == 2 )))
        .Returns(2);
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because let's say I have a list of 10 elements and the behavior is that for some of them I need a result, and for the others I need another result. So I need to Mock somehow based on the value inside of the object.

Comment: @kord Then you can use `It.Is`. I updated my answer with details